# an easy way to subdivide along one axis only?

Tags: mesh

I'm making a rope for a game so it needs to be low poly. If I create a cylinder and subdivide, I get too many vertices around the circumference which I don't want. I only want to add vertices to the length axis, like slicing a cucumber for a salad.

I know I can use the knife tool (k key) together with the z key to cut though once, but, to do that say 100 times is a pain and it is also not as precise as I want the cuts to be.

Is there any way to automate that or is there a better version of the system subdivide command?

Answer (score 38):

I think the command you are looking for is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and scroll mouse button to add/subtract loops, and then <kbd>LMB</kbd> to accept loop count and then <kbd>RMB</kbd> to confirm location of loops.
[image]

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html#options

Comment: scroll your middle mouse button after you Ctrl+R

Comment: The link is now https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/loopcut_slide.html

Answer (score 26):

You may subdivide in a 'lenght' axis with <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide* but you have to select only the 'lenght axis' edges. Enable the *edge selection* mode and select them (with <kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd> ), then subdivide with <kbd>W</kbd>. You'll also have some extra options (like *Fractal*) in a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) then. You can use it to randomise your rope's shape.
[image]

Comment: thanks, this looks even easier than the ctrl-r option, both are good, thanks for the quick replies. the blenderartists forum takes days to get a reply, this is way better